# Border only left top on Flutter TextField

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, border, textfield

I was wondering if it is possible to have borders only on specific sides on Flutter TextField. In this particular case, I need only top and left, but would like to know in general if this is possible, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can wrap the TextField widget with Container and give border:

```
Container(
 decoration: BoxDecoration(
 color: Colors.white,
 border: Border(
  top: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
  left: BorderSide(color: Colors.red),
  ),
 ),
 child: TextFormField(
  decoration: InputDecoration(
   labelText: 'Email',
   border: InputBorder.none,
  ),
 ),
),
```

the result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sure you can, try this (or check DartPad I made for it : https://dartpad.dev/1a28bdd9203250d3226cc25d512579ec?null_safety=true):

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            border: Border(
              top: BorderSide(width: 4.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
              left: BorderSide(width: 4.0, color: Colors.lightBlue.shade900),
            ),
          ),
          child: TextField(),
        ),
      ),
```

[image]

Comment: So it cannot be done from the TextField boders, that have different properties for enabled, disabled and error? It needs to be wrapped in a container?

Comment: No, not from the TextField borders.